# 2 tables 1 web app what do I do

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller, crud

I have two tables named Earnings and Passengers now I have these codes

view starting with this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="mrtservlet" method="post">
Enter first name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Enter last name: <input type="text" name="lname">
Destination: <input type="text" name="dest">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

now I must send the fname lname and dest to the Passengers table and the Earnings must base its entries on the dest example if I put guadalupe in as dest the earnings table must have an entry of 1 and 20 one two columns with 1 being the stop number and 20 being the price to get there

here are my beans

```
package model;

public class earnings {
private int fare;
private int sno;

public int getfare(){
    return fare;
    }
public void setfare(int fare){
    this.fare = fare;
    }
public int getsno(){
    return sno;
    }
public void setsno(int sno){
    this.sno = sno;
    }
}
```

and

```
package model;

public class passengers {
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String dest;

public String getfname(){
    return fname;
    }
public void setfname(String fname){
    this.fname = fname;
    }
public String getlname(){
    return lname;
    }
public void setlname(String lname){
    this.lname = lname;
    }
public String getdest(){
    return dest;
    }
public void setdest(String dest){
    this.dest = dest;
    }
}
```

and my utilities for the sql commands and connections

```
package utilities;

 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class earnings_connection {

private static Connection connection = null;

public static Connection getConnection() {
     if (connection != null)
     return connection;
     else {
     try {
     Properties prop = new Properties();
     InputStream=inputStreampassengers_connection.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties0");
     prop.load(inputStream);
     String driver = prop.getProperty("driver");
     String url = prop.getProperty("url");
     String user = prop.getProperty("user");
     String password = prop.getProperty("password");
     Class.forName(driver);
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return connection;
     }
    }   
}
```

connection for the earnings(above) and connection for the passengers(below)
    package utilities;

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class passengers_connection {

private static Connection connection = null;

public static Connection getConnection() {
     if (connection != null)
     return connection;
     else {
     try {
     Properties prop = new Properties();
     InputStream inputStream = passengers_connection.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
     prop.load(inputStream);
     String driver = prop.getProperty("driver");
     String url = prop.getProperty("url");
     String user = prop.getProperty("user");
     String password = prop.getProperty("password");
     Class.forName(driver);
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return connection;
     }

    }
    }
```

The sql operations the tables are going to use first for the earnings

```
package utilities;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import model.earnings;

public class earnings_dao {

private Connection connection;

public earnings_dao(){
    connection = utilities.passengers_connection.getConnection(); 
    }

    public void insertrip(earnings user) { 
        try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
        .prepareStatement("insert into Earnings(Stop No,Fare)"
                + "values (?, ?)");
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, user.getsno());
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, user.getfare());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<earnings> getAllUsers() {
        List<earnings> users = new ArrayList<earnings>();
        try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select Stop No from Earnings");
        while (rs.next()) {
        earnings user = new earnings();
        user.setsno(rs.getInt("Stop No"));
        users.add(user);}
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return users;
    }   
}
```

now for the passengers

```
package utilities;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import model.passengers;


public class passengers_dao {

private Connection connection;

public passengers_dao(){
connection = utilities.passengers_connection.getConnection(); 
}

public void insertrip(passengers user) { 
    try {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
    .prepareStatement("insert into Passengers(firstname,lastname,destination)"
            + "values (?, ?, ?)");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getfname());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getlname());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getdest());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
}
```

now i'm stuck with my controller can anyone point out anything wrong I've done with my code it would be greatly appreciated if it helps I used MySQL Server Management Studio to create the database and their tables I have'nt done the mapping yet

Comment: You lack the servlet itself, do you have it defined somewhere?

You need to tell the application server what is supose to handle the /mrtservlet path

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what is the issue is, but in the question I don't see the any declaration of the Servlet you are trying to post back to so i'm going to assume that's the issue:

You can define the Servlet class that will handle both get and post requests done to the url defined.

Going to use in the answer the JAVA convention naming for the classes and try to do some code which hopefully can help you.

```
@WebServlet(name = "mrtservlet", urlPatterns = {"/mrtservlet"}})
public class Mrtservlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //do the get stuff if necessary
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //read the post parameters to temporary variables
        String fname= req.getParameter("fname");
        String lname= req.getParameter("lname");
        String dest= req.getParameter("dest");
         // do some null checks on the fields you get from the request

        //fill the earning with what you want and do all the dao related stuf
        Earning earning = new Earning();

        EarningsDao earningsDao= new EarningsDao();
        earningsDao.insert(earning);

        //You can wrap the above code in a switch or a if's if you want to do something different for each dest 
        if(dest!=null && dest.equals("guadalupe")){
         //do guadalupe related stuff
        }

        //redirect to any servlet/page you want you want

        resp.sendRedirect("/servlet");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made the servlet already its just that I cant grasp the concept of what do i need to the in the servlet part yeah being forced to do this with poor background in serlvets just an idea would be nice

Comment: I'll try to add a few more details to the answer then

Comment: Also class names should be in camel case, like EarningsDao instead of earnings_dao